# Taxonomy breadcrumbs - only show one level back

Tags: taxonomy

I have a taxonomy tree with two levels.
[image]

When I am on a page at the second level, i.e., Sales & Management Training, breadcrumbs look like this

```
< Careers < Training Programs
```

But I only want to see the level immediately above the current page, which is:

```
< Training Programs
```

I don't see a way to do this built in the the Taxonomy breadcrumb tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love when I answer my own question. Instead of the breadcrumbs tag, just use get_node: http://iain.co.nz/software/docs/taxonomy3-get-node

This lets you get information about the parent, which is all we need. It's like a single, elegant, delicious little breadcrumb.

```
{exp:taxonomy:get_node tree_id="2" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <a href="{this_parent_node_url}">< Back</a>
{/exp:taxonomy:get_node}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditionals with a single variable like `node_level` to determine what is shown:

```
{exp:taxonomy:breadcrumbs}
    {if node_level > 1}
        {if here}
            {node_title}
        {if:else}
            <a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a> &rarr; 
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/exp:taxonomy:breadcrumbs}
```

Comment: The problem is that if I'm at level 2, I need to show level 1, and if I'm at level 1, I need to show level 0 (the single, top-level entry). Make sense?